# Orchard CMS Multi-tenancy crash beware

Tags: orchardcms

I'm sporting Orchard 1.4 up with Multi-tenancy enabled. I added a new tenant this morning with a name that started with the number 4, "4wdcarsandtrucks". Well, after creating the new tenant, all my sites started throwing 404 errors. Looking into the logs, I found that I was getting the following entries for every one of my tentants:

> 2012-05-20 08:59:22,795 [6] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - A
>   tenant could not be started: Default System.Xml.XmlException: Name
>   cannot begin with the '4' character, hexadecimal value 0x34. Line 16,
>   position 4.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res,
>   String[] args)    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean
>   isQName, Int32 startOffset, Int32& colonPos)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)    at
>   Orchard.Environment.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorCache.Fetch(String name)
>   in
>   C:\src\xxxxxx\main\dotnet\public\Orchard\v1.4.1.0\src\Orchard\Environment\Descriptor\ShellDescriptorCache.cs:line
>   53    at
>   Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings
>   settings) in
>   C:\src\xxxxx\main\dotnet\public\Orchard\v1.4.1.0\src\Orchard\Environment\ShellBuilders\ShellContextFactory.cs:line
>   54    at
>   Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateAndActivateShells() in
>   C:\src\xxxxxx\main\dotnet\public\Orchard\v1.4.1.0\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:line
>   135

As per instructions of removing tentants manually, I deleted the site folder in App_Data\Sites and the issue still persists.

I did a search under the orchard root folder for "4wdcarsandtrucks" and found another folder in Media. With that removed, the only remaining traces of the tenant name, the issues still persists. I've Recycled the app pool and restarted the site. It's so bizarre!

Has anyone run into this issue before or anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue resolved! Okay, in case anyone else runs into this, there is some bizzare caching surrounding this issue. The following steps should clear it right up:

1. Stop the application pool.
2. Delete App_Data\cache.dat
3. Start the application pool.

Answer (score 1):

I had a local copy of server's side Orchard CMS and I had an uninitialized tenant on my azure server. After downloading it, it either wanted to set up a new webpage (default setup screen on an already working system) or it threw

> a tenant could not be started

But deleting `cache.dat` in `App_Data` folder of my orchard directory (locally) fixed the issue.